# Why does the loss of Word2Vec model trained by gensim at first increase for a few epochs and then decrease?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, loss

Actually this is a sequel to:
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781667/why-does-the-loss-value-of-a-word2vec-model-become-zero-after-a-few-epochs)

I am training a Word2Vec model using gensim, with parameters hs=1, sg=0 and negative=0. Less training time is required after the code is modified, but something seems to go wrong with the loss, it would at first increase then decrease, I don't know what happened.

The code is as follows:

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
from gensim.models import word2vec
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', 
level=logging.INFO)
sentences = word2vec.Text8Corpus("text8")   # loading the corpus




from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec
loss_list = []
    
class Callback(CallbackAny2Vec):
def __init__(self):
    self.epoch = 0

def on_epoch_end(self, model):
    loss = model.get_latest_training_loss()
    loss_list.append(loss)
    print('Loss after epoch {}:{}'.format(self.epoch, loss))
    model.running_training_loss = 0.0
    self.epoch = self.epoch + 1




from gensim.models import KeyedVectors,word2vec,Word2Vec
import time

start_time = time.time()

model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, hs=1, sg=0, negative=0, compute_loss=True, epochs=30, callbacks=[Callback()])

end_time = time.time()

print('Running time: %s seconds' % (end_time - start_time))
```

The codes are actually written in jupyter, as can be seen in the screenshot:

[image: code]

and the output is like this:

[image: output]

More details about the output:

```
Loss after epoch 0:39370848.0
Loss after epoch 1:43579636.0
Loss after epoch 2:45213772.0
Loss after epoch 3:46132356.0
Loss after epoch 4:46788412.0
Loss after epoch 5:47218508.0
Loss after epoch 6:47553520.0
Loss after epoch 7:47793332.0
Loss after epoch 8:47995616.0
Loss after epoch 9:48134664.0
Loss after epoch 10:48224960.0
Loss after epoch 11:48326640.0
Loss after epoch 12:48371072.0
Loss after epoch 13:48405980.0
Loss after epoch 14:48437804.0
Loss after epoch 15:48417612.0
Loss after epoch 16:48415112.0
Loss after epoch 17:48396260.0
Loss after epoch 18:48349064.0
Loss after epoch 19:48301088.0
Loss after epoch 20:48247328.0
Loss after epoch 21:48167340.0
Loss after epoch 22:48053500.0
Loss after epoch 23:47937300.0
Loss after epoch 24:47810964.0
Loss after epoch 25:47669088.0
Loss after epoch 26:47500524.0
Loss after epoch 27:47300488.0
Loss after epoch 28:47044920.0
Loss after epoch 29:46747080.0

Running time: 259.9046218395233 seconds
```

Comment: Do the vectors work well on task-specific evaluations? That, moreso than loss trends, is the reliable indicator of whether your approach is working. I wouldn't expect the trend shown in your graph in usual loss reporting. But, are you sure that's a chart of the right data? I'm not seeing the output of your run, or any code purporting to display the `loss_list` data.

Comment: Yeah that's the right data, I'll add it to the question body.

Comment: I tested the model's effect on a text classification task, that is, I prepared many film reviews each of which was labeled as either one or zero, these labels were used for identifying whether a review is a positive one or a negative one, and the task was to test if the model could predict the right labels for the reviews. As a result, I think the model was working well, I ended up with a confusion matrix with a recall of about 0.869, and accuracy of about 0.856.

Comment: But I don't know if that means I don't have to care about the loss

Comment: The legitimate use of a loss-readout is to determine if the model has "converged". That is, by the end of training, has loss decreased to a level where it seems to "get stuck" & not go any lower? If so, that means the model has become "as good as it can" (under the current parameters/data). Further training that improves it for some training-examples/words is then also damaging other examples/words – providing no net improvement wrt training goals. So the model is essentially "done", and you'd need to look to other model-choices/tuning/better-data if it's not good enough on downstream tasks.

Comment: Yeah that's a good solution, I will keep trying some other models and tasks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect that pattern of rising-then-falling loss; I would think that usual SGD optimization would usually ahieve falling full-epoch loss from the very beginning.

However, if the end result vectors are still performing well, I wouldn't worry too much about surprises in secondary progress indicators, like that loss tally, for a number of reasons:

- as noted in my previous answer (& further discussed in the [Gensim project open issue #2617](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2617)), Gensim's external loss-reporting has a number of known bugs & inconsistencies. Any oddness in observed loss-reporting may be a side-effect of those issues, without necessarily indicating any problem with the actual training updates.
- it appears you're finishing 30 training epochs in 260 seconds – each full training pass in under 9 seconds. That suggests your training data is pretty tiny – perhaps too small to be a good example of word2vec capabilities, or too small for the default 100-dimensional vectors. That smallness, or other peculiarities in the training data, might contribute to atypical loss trends, or exercising some of the other weaknesses of the current loss-tallying code. *If* the same hard-to-explain pattern occurs with a more typical training corpus – such as one 100x larger – then it'd be more interesting to do a deep-dive investigation to understand what's happening. But unexpected results on tiny/unusual/atypical training runs might just be because such runs are far from where the usual intuitions apply, and getting to the bottom of their causes less productive than acquiring enough data to run the algorithm in a more typical/reliable way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess it could be attributed to the bugs and inconsistencies, but I don't think that the training data is tiny, it's text8 dataset that I use for this program and it's a very large dataset, what's more, I change the default vector size to 300 and it doesn't get better.

Comment: Maybe I should change the vector size to a much bigger value.

Comment: `text8` is a very tiny dataset, much smaller than is usually used with word2vec, as also evidenced by your epochs completing in <9s. While it's possible to demo word2vec results in training sessions that last just minutes, it is an algorithm that inherently needs large & varied training data for good results, and training sessions that last many hours are more typical. (For larger datasets/vocabularies, multi-day training sessions are even common.)

Comment: Making the `vector_size` larger is the exact **wrong** thing to do if your data is insufficient. You never want your model to be larger than your data, or even really anywhere close to it in size. The whole point of machine-learning/advanced-modelling is typically to **compress** the patterns in a larger dataset into a more generalizable, compact set of relationships. If your model is anywhere near as large as your data, it will tend towards "overfitting", memorizing idiosyncracies in the data rather than generalizable patterns. Shrinking, not growing, the model may then help.

Comment: Oh really? I don't know about that...The first version of my program was trained with text8 and it did take me quite a lot of time...Anyway, thank you for pointing out all the misconceptions!